# Javascript - setting prototype from inside function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

This works:

```
function Bird(name){
    Animal.call(this,name);
    this.speak = function(){
        console.log("Tweeet!");
    }
}
Bird.prototype.constructor = Animal;
```

This throws "Cannot set property 'constructor' of undefined"

```
function Bird(name){
    Animal.call(this,name);
    this.speak = function(){
        console.log("Tweeet!");
    }
    this.prototype.constructor = Animal;
}
```

Why would that be?  In the second example, **this** should be **Bird** as I have called the function with **new**, so I should be able to set the prototype of **this**.  What am I missing here?

Comment: `this` inside function - object, so it don't have prototype property, but if you change `this` to `Bird` all should work

Comment: Just answering my own question, now that I understand JavaScript a little better.  In the second example, 'this' is not 'Bird' - 'this' is a new object that  has been created and passed to the Bird function.

Answer (score 2):

An `Object` instance (`this`) does not have a `prototype` property, so `this.prototype` returns `undefined`.

You have two options to get around this:

1. Call `Bird.prototype` as you did in the first snippet:

   ```
   function Bird(name){
       Animal.call(this,name);
       this.speak = function(){
           console.log("Tweeet!");
       }
       Bird.prototype.constructor = Animal;
   }
   ```
2. Use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get hold of the prototype of the object:

   ```
   function Bird(name){
       Animal.call(this,name);
       this.speak = function(){
           console.log("Tweeet!");
       }
       Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor = Animal;
   }
   ```

Option 2 is more useful when you don't know what type the object is. In your example, you are inside the `Bird` class, so option 1 makes more sense.

---

Here is a working example which will hopefully make the question in your comment clearer:

```js
// 1. Tell Javascript what an Animal is
// This will create an Object called Animal, but it is a blueprint not an actual Animal.

function Animal(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

// 2. Tell Javascript what a Bird is
// This will create an Object called Bird, but it is a blueprint not an actual Bird. So it cannot speak!

// or function Bird(name){
var Bird = function(name){
    Animal.call(this,name);
    this.speak = function(){
        alert("Tweeet! said " + this.name);
    }
    
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor = Animal;
};

// 3. Now create an actual Bird which can speak 

var tweety = new Bird("Tweety Pie");
tweety.speak();
```

Comment: Thanks Rhumborl.  I think I may be misunderstanding how functions work.  This is how I think it works: As JS has no classes,  when I define **function Bird(){}** that function is instantiated as an object on the current context.  Am I wrong here?  Can a function exist that is not an instantiated object?

Comment: @wagster try see about [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). When you define function - you define function, when you instantiate object - you instanteate object

Comment: @wagster Yes what you are saying sounds correct but you may be mixing up the types of objects. In JS, _everything_ is an object, including functions, so `function Bird(){}` will create an object of type `Function` with name `Bird` in the current scope. In fact to make it clearer you can write it as `var Bird = function(){}`. At this point, no Birds actually exist, you have just told JS how to create one. If you want an actual `Bird`, you will need to use `var canary = new Bird("Tweety Pie")`. It is _this_ call which will actually run your `Bird` method and give you an object of type `Bird`.